# configuring more than one {{> uploader}} in one page

Tags: meteor

I have an {{> uploader}} to get the user selected image. the problem is i want to add another {{> uploader}} with different configuration to get another input from user ".zip format".  using {{> uploader}} twice, the same code will function for both of them.

is it possible to use {{> uploader}} twice and give each one its different configuration?

this is the code to configure the type of images the user can upload, how can i set this restriction to {{>uploader config="1"}}

```
   Slingshot.fileRestrictions( "string", {
  allowedFileTypes: [ "image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/gif" ],
maxSize: null
});
```

This is how i did it

```
Template.upload.rendered = function(){
  if (upload.instance().data['config'] === '1') { 
        Slingshot.fileRestrictions( "string", {
    allowedFileTypes: [ "image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/gif" ],
    maxSize: null
  });
    } else if (upload.instance().data['config'] === '2') { 
      Slingshot.fileRestrictions( "string", {
    allowedFileTypes: [ "image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/gif" ],
    maxSize: null
  });

    }
}
```

but i get this error

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'rendered' of undefined
    at server/fileName.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** look like you are using the code from [here](https://github.com/themeteorchef/uploading-files-to-amazon-s3) as an example

You can pass the flag to the template in order to brach the configuration inside the uploader

```
{{> uploader config="1"}} 
{{> uploader config="2"}}
```

Then inside the template, depending on the flag, you can do

```
    // uploader.js
    Template.uploader.events({
        'change input[type="file"]' ( event, template ) {
            Modules.client.uploadToAmazonS3( { event: event, template: template, config: Template.instance().data['config'] } );
        }
    });
```

Now, change the upload-to-amazon.js

```
let _uploadFileToAmazon = ( file, config ) => {
  var uploader;
  if (config === '1') {
      uploader = new Slingshot.Upload( "uploadToAmazonS3Cg1" );
  } else {
      uploader = new Slingshot.Upload( "uploadToAmazonS3Cg2" );
  }

  uploader.send( file, ( error, url ) => {
    if ( error ) {
      Bert.alert( error.message, "warning" );
      _setPlaceholderText();
    } else {
      _addUrlToDatabase( url );
    }
  });
};

let upload = ( options ) => {
  template = options.template;
  let file = _getFileFromInput( options.event );
  let config = options.config;

  _setPlaceholderText( `Uploading ${file.name}...` );
  _uploadFileToAmazon( file, config );
};
```

And finally change the server/slingshot.js

```
Slingshot.fileRestrictions( "uploadToAmazonS3Cg1", {
  ....
});

Slingshot.fileRestrictions( "uploadToAmazonS3Cg2", {
  .... 
});

Slingshot.createDirective( "uploadToAmazonS3Cg1", Slingshot.S3Storage, {
   ...
});

Slingshot.createDirective( "uploadToAmazonS3Cg2", Slingshot.S3Storage, {
   ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks, trying it now

Comment: i edited the question and added the code to configure the type of images the user can upload, how can i set this restriction to {{>uploader config="1"}}

Comment: Thanks, trying it now :)

Comment: the app crashes, "Cannot set property 'rendered' of undefined
    at server/slingshot.js:1:25"

Comment: err, `rendered` is the function for the template on the client side. Did you complete the meteor tutorial ?

Comment: i did the todo tutorial only and just dived in in implementation, it's the ideal way to learn to me :)

Comment: the template is in the client side but the code responsible for checking the type of the file is on the server side,

Comment: isn't it possible to keep it on the server side?